# Who is the Fielding of Temporal Database modeling?

Tags: computer-science, database-design, temporal-database

It doesn't take very much reading on REST before you run across Fielding and his [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)

IF you've had some wins with temporal modeling within the confines of a relational store Who are the big names in the field that you referenced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Richard Snodgrass](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/cv.pdf) has been granted ACM Fellow for his research in temporal databases filed.

Also Citeseer has [one of his papers on the topic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.136.4755), which is quite highly referenced.

He is also the author of the book [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Richard Snodgrass, Chris Date & Hugh Darwen, Dan Linstedt